# export certain users using CSV file in AD

Tags: csv, active-directory, export

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI2GF.png)
Can someone help me with an issue of extracting certain users using UPN from AD.
File is CSV but I can change that.
I need Job title,location,address from all of the users and there is 179 of them.
Any help appreciated

I was trying

$csv2 = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\userslocations.csv"
Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq "$csv2.Userprincipalname"}

and that

Import-Csv -Path "C:\path\to\file.csv" | ForEach-Object {

Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$($_.Username)'" -Properties Name, Mail, CO, title | select  name, mail, CO, title | Export-Csv -Path "C:\path\to\output.csv" -Append

}
and truly was going around that, mostly it was creating empty file but with different versions of that code

Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity:
or
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'userPrincipalName